# Linux (Deepin OS) Headset Microphone

Tags: linux, drivers, microphone, headphones, headset

I started using Deepin OS few days ago, and i was user of Archlinux before this and on the both distros i am issuing the same problem.

Basically my point is, i can't actually use the headset microphone when i have headset connected into my PC, it seems like my OS can't detect the microphone at all, the only microphone detected as input device on my system is the built-in microphone at all times.

I have tried installing the Realtek HD Audio drivers but i couldn't compile the drivers.. some are saying they are old and they are not supported by newer kernels etc but whatsoever i need help fixing this as fast as possible! Here is a system information log produced by "alsa-info":

http://www.alsa-project.org/db/?f=054311ea09431a60373580ca600373740aafc7db

The headset that im using is mobile headset from my Samsung Galaxy S7.
Also to mention that i was issuing this problem on Windows 7 as well, but it all got fixed after i installed the audio drivers for my laptop.
Now everytime that im plugging in something into my pc a window pops-up and i have to select what i have plugged in (Speakers/Line-in/Headphones/Headset).
When im selecting Headphones i have the same result as here on linux, the audio output goes to headset, but as a microphone im stil using the built-in microphone, but if i switch to "Headset" all works like charm.

Comment: Please [edit] and include details of the headset you are using